# How to create shared views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, shared

In my Views folder I have a several folders such as Category, Origin, Price,.... They all have a Browse.aspx file and the code in this file displays a table of products. All controllers associated with these folders use the same ViewModel, but in each view I have a repetitive code. The code is:

Folder Category, file browse.aspx
Folder Origin, file browse.aspx
.....

```
<% foreach ( var p in Model.Products) { %>
    <li> <%: p.productname + " " + p.price + " " + p.origin.originname + " " + p.category.categoryname %> </li>
<% } %>
```

How can I create a shared view and use the shared view in all these views?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like ther ar two things you can do:

1. Pull the repetitive view code into a partial view.
2. Put the partial view in the 'Shared' view folder.

Then you can render this partial view in your other views.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can set a parameter to the Index method of your view (You'd have to merge this controllers into only one)

and according to this parameter you make a switch. Each case would then request only the type wanted

```
public ActionResult Index(String a)
    switch (a)
       {
           case "1":  //set your model the way you want it ...
       }
```